# Cannot install wine32 because of dependencies

Tags: apt, wine, parrotsec

OS: Parrot Security (Debian based)

I'm trying to install wine32 but it throws dependency errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4:i386 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
 libvkd3d1:i386 : Depends: libvulkan1:i386 (>= 1.1.70) but it is not going to be installed
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libgl1:i386 but it is not installable
                Recommends: libglu1-mesa:i386 but it is not installable or
                            libglu1:i386
                Recommends: libsane1:i386 (>= 1.0.27) but it is not installable
                Recommends: libvulkan1:i386 (>= 1.2.131.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I looked at some other people's errors and it seems that my dependencies are different from others

I've tried:

- `apt -f install`
- `apt --fix-broken install`
- `apt install && apt update`
- `aptitude -f install wine32` (aptitude command doesn't exist)
- `dpkg --add-architecture i386`

How can I fix this?

`apt policy libldap-2.4-2:{amd64,i386}` outputs

```
libldap-2.4-2:
  Installed: 2.4.59+dfsg-1~bpo11+1
  Candidate: 2.4.59+dfsg-1~bpo11+1
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.59+dfsg-1~bpo11+1 599
        599 deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.57+dfsg-3 600
        600 deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot/main amd64 Packages
libldap-2.4-2:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.57+dfsg-3
  Version table:
     2.4.59+dfsg-1~bpo11+1 599
        599 deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-backports/main i386 Packages
     2.4.57+dfsg-3 600
        600 deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot/main i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve installed the `amd64` versions of at least some of the dependencies from backports, so you need to install `wine32` from backports as well:

```
sudo apt install -t parrot-backports wine32
```